# Windows Runtime Component namespace and internal member visibility

Tags: namespaces, internal, c++-cx

sorry, I am new in C++ CX, I am starting a new project and have a few questions...

1) How can I create WRT component in namespace **A.B.C** ? When I use dots, my project is in namespace **A_B_C**, when I change namespaces in code I get error APPX1706: The .winmd file 'A_B_C.winmd' contains type 'A.B.C.class' outside its root namespace 'A_B_C'. What shoud I do ?

2) I want to use DirectX internally in the Component. I need to share some internal members ( like Matrix3x2F, Device... and so on ) internally between public classes inside DLL, but when I use **internal:** keyword, I get message  **106 IntelliSense: public data members are not allowed in non-value types**. Is there any solution of this issue ?

Thank for help...

example :

```
public ref class CLS1 sealed
{
public:
    CLS1();

internal:
    // get error here
    D2D1::Matrix3x2F matrix;
};

public ref class CLS2 sealed
{
public:
    CLS2();

    void Render( CLS1^ cls1)
    {
        // need to access internal member here !
        // error
        cls1->matrix->Invert();
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd highly suggest splitting this up into two separate questions with a code example for each. RE: #1 are you asking how to nest namespace in the code or in project settings?

Answer (score 3):

now I have solution for number 1 problem... do not know if it is ideal..

1) In Visual Studio I create a new project-> Windows Runtime Component -> Project name = **"A.B.C.CompName"**
2) Visual studio creates class in namespace **"A_B_C_CompName"**
3) I change namespace to

```
namespace A{
namespace B{
namespace C{

... component code here

}}}
```

4) In "A.B.C.Name.Windows.vcxproj" I manually change xml from

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{fcd4484d-b812-4b16-919b-b23292bdf3c5}</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>A_B_C_Name</RootNamespace>...
```

to

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
        <ProjectGuid>{fcd4484d-b812-4b16-919b-b23292bdf3c5}</ProjectGuid>
        <RootNamespace>A.B.C</RootNamespace>...
```

And now I have a new component in namespace A.B.C; If somebody has a better way how to do it, please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

The WinRTComponent DLL tries to simplify what is otherwise a somewhat complicated machinery.

- VS registers your WinRT component when you build your solution.  And by register, I mean it adds the information about this component into the AppX manifest of the app.
- In order for the runtime classes inside your project to be activatable, the name of the winmd file corresponding to your WinRT component needs to match the top-level namespace of your runtime classes.

When you use the default settings for a WinRTComponent DLL template, VS ensures that all of the above requirements are fulfilled.  It generates sources/headers with the same namespace name as the project name, which also happens to be the name of the output winmd file.

However, when you rename the component, your output winmd has a different name but your namespace inside your code is still the old one.  They need to match.  And, yes you can have multiple runtime classes in your project as long as they are in the same namespace.

Btw, I see a small problem with your code.  It should be:

```
cls1->matrix.Invert();
```

Comment: Public (in the winmd) types don't need to be in the same namespace, subnamespaces are fine, but they do need to be in or below the namespace implied by the file name.

Answer (score 0):

1) Dot is the filename nesting delimiter. So the file should be named A.B.C.winmd/dll, and the namespace of the root-most public type should be in the namespace A::B::C. If the file is named A_B_C.winmd, that implies a single namespace named A_B_C.

2) Try making an accessor method and keeping the member variable private. You can make the accessor return D2D1::Matrix3x2F&. This should work fine.